# I am trying to open .rb file but I get an error message "in '<main>'undefined local variable or method 'quit for main: Object (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, syntax-error

I'm completely new to this and I am following a course to learn coding but I can't seem to open the .rb files I downloaded with the course to follow along. In the video he double clicks the .rb file and command prompt opens with the code but when I double click the file my command prompt opens then immediately closes so I'm trying to open it manually by navigating to the directory where the program is located in command prompt. In ruby I type "cd Desktop" since the .rb file is on my desktop then I type "ruby 02_02integers.rb" which is the name of the file (I press tab after typing "02" since it fills the rest automatically") but when I press enter I get the error message above. This is the code in the .rb file I'm trying to open in command prompt, he's basically just showing different examples of integers.

```
# This file is a transcript of the IRB session shown in the movie.
# You should be able to cut and paste it into IRB to get 
# the same results shown in the comments.

# irb
1 + 1
# => 2
x = 2
# => 2
4 / 2
# => 2
4 * 2
# => 8
4 - 2
# => 2
4 ** 2
# => 16
x = 4
# => 4
x += 2
# => 6
x
# => 6
x = x + 2
# => 8
(1 + 2) * 3
# => 9
1234.class
# => Fixnum
123456789123456789.class
# => Bignum
x = 1234 * 1234 * 1234
# => 1879080904
x.class
# => Bignum
-200
# => -200
-200.abs
# => 200
200.next
# => 201
quit
```

Answer (score 0):

The author has left this comment in the file:

```
# This file is a transcript of the IRB session shown in the movie.
# You should be able to cut and paste it into IRB to get 
# the same results shown in the comments.
```

it's telling you to copy and paste it into irb.

If you remove the `quit` line then it should have the same effect when you run it with `ruby` instead of `irb`, but the `quit` method is actually defined in irb and not in ruby-core.

The `exit` command does the same thing and will work in both cases.

Comment: Oh okay so I just need to remove the quit line from the code and re save it without the quit line? So do I copy and paste the code into my text editor, remove the quit line then save as a new .rb file without the quit line?

Comment: I just want to be able to open the file by navigating to the file through the directory in command prompt and opening through ruby rather than copying and pasting the code into irb.

Comment: then yeah, either remove the quit (which is unnecessary when running a file because it will automatically quit when finished) or change it to `exit`.

Comment: Okay again really sorry for being so full of questions but last question promise! So do I drag the file into my text editor, remove the quit line from the code/text then save as a new .rb file without the quit line? Because I tried that, then navigated to the directory and did "ruby (file name.rb)" and pressed enter and it still didn't work.

Comment: don't apologize, i'm the one choosing to spend time answering questions.  I'm assuming you know how to edit a file. All you need to do is remove the `quit` line.

Comment: if you don't know how to edit a file without creating a new file, you should get some more experience in general computer usage before learning code.

Comment: Okay great, well I'm just not sure how to edit a ruby file in particular? Once I get this answered I'll be all done woo!

Comment: it depends on what operating system and text editor you're using. But usually you just open the existing file in the text editor, edit it, then file => save. But this isn't really a programming question, so it's not suited to stack overflow.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for taking the time to help me out I really appreciate it and learned exactly what to do. You're awesome!!